# Prove that $2x$ is irreducible, but not prime in the ring of polynomials whose all coefficients, excepting the constant term, are even numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $$R=\{f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]:\text{ all  coefficients of }f, \text{ except  possibly the constant term, are even numbers}\}.$$  E.g., $1+6x+8x^2$ and $4+4x+10x^2$ are in $R$, but $2+5x$ is not in $R$. Prove that $R$ is an integral domain and $2x$ is an irreducible, but not prime, element of $R$.

I have tried to prove this by using cases such as $ab = 0$ if $a$ has constant even and $b$ constant odd and so on, then trying to show that either of $a$ or $b$ must be $0$ but I'm not getting it and I don't think that's the right approach. How can I show that $R$ is an integral domain?  Also, how will I show that $2x$ is irreducible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for all of these problems, consider $R$ as a sub-ring of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

For the first part, recall that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a integral domain – what can we conclude about subrings of integral domains?

For the second part, note that any factorization of $2x$ in $R$ will also be a factorization of $2x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and recall that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a unique factorization domain (thus in particular, the only factorizations of $2x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ up to units are the obvious ones). Can you finish this argument?

For the third part, note that every multiple of $2x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ will also be in the subring $R$. (Why?) So in particular, to come up with good candidates to witness the failure of $2x$ to be prime in $R$, think about those elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that are multiples of $2x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ but not in $R$. Example below:

> For instance, $2x$ divides $4x^2=(2x)(2x)$ in $R$, but we also have that $4x^2=2\cdot(2x^2)$, both factors of which lie in $R$ but neither factor of which is a multiple of $2x$ in $R$.

Comment: You omitted an important part, that $2x$ is not prime in $R\ \ \ $

Comment: OP did not ask about that so I assumed they had a solution. @Ka Em do you also need help showing that $2x$ is not prime?

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't understand why you said neither of which is a multiple of $2x$ in $R$

Comment: @KaEm $2x$ does not divide $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so certainly $2x$ does not divide $2$ in $R$. To see that $2x$ does not divide $2x^2$ in $R$ consider the hint that I wrote; in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have $2x^2=(2x)*x$, but $x\notin R$.

Comment: Okay, got it. Please can you elaborate more on $2x$ being irreducible? @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: @KaEm Sure. Any factorization of $2x$ in $R$ will also be a factorization of $2x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Now, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD, and both $2$ and $x$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and so the only non-trivial factorization of $2x$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (up to units, so in this ring up to multiplication by $\pm 1$) is given by $2*x$. But this is not a factorization in $R$, as $x\notin R$, and so $2x$ admits no non-trivial factorizations in $R$.

Comment: @KaEm In general this is often a good way of doing this kind of problem; if you want to show that a polynomial (or more generally an element in a ring) is irreducible, but it is not immediately clear, embed the ring into a larger ring in which the element does factor. Then show that none of the possible factorizations in the larger ring induces a factorization in the smaller ring.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to comment that I understood your explanation on why $2x$ is irreducible. Thank you.

Comment: @KaEm great, glad to help :)